# estimate a truncated normal distribution with only top tail of data of that distribution in r

Tags: r

I am trying to fit a truncated normal distribution to a data, however my problem is I only have top tail of the data/distribution (and I wouldn't know what percentile they are because I dont know about the real distribution's mean and variance yet), by which I want to construct back the truncated normal distribution and get it's estimated mean and variance. The package I used was fitdistrplus::fitdistr.

The codes I tried are as following:

```
dtnorm.trun1 <- function(x, mean, sd, a= 8.414596, b=Inf) 
    dnorm(x, mean, sd)/(pnorm(b,mean,sd)-pnorm(a,mean,sd))

ptnorm.trun1 <- function(x, mean, sd, a= 8.414596, b=Inf) 
  (pnorm(x, mean, sd)-pnorm(a,mean,sd))/(pnorm(b,mean,sd)-pnorm(a,mean, sd))

fit <- fitdistr(data, dtnorm.trun1, method="Nelder-Mead", start=list(mean=-24, sd=21))
```

I'm doing this practice for replication, so I expect I should be getting fitted mean of -24 and sd of 21, and the real data was truncated at 8.414596. With different starting values and different estimation method, I won't be getting my expected result. I'm really confused about this. Thank you in advance for any suggestion and advise.

Comment: This is probably a better question for [stats.se] since you seem to be concerned with statistical estimation rather than programming.

Comment: @MrFlick thank you for editing and the suggestion, I will post the question there too. But I also was wondering is it because I understood this package incorrectly or use it wrong..